# Full table scan while trying to eliminate duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

This subquery is part of a larger query:

```
(SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id,
    mi_id,
    m_id
  FROM members  USE INDEX (idx_member)
  WHERE 
  (1=1 )
  GROUP BY   mi_id,
    m_id
  )
```

The reason for doing that is to eliminate duplicate rows and pick up the maximum.

However, out of about 100 K rows, I only have 30-40 rows that are duplicate, but this is forcing full table scan . The index is on m_id .

Any ways to resolve this without using MAX / aggregation ?

Comment: That is how MySQL does aggregations.  Often, correlated subqueries make better use of indexes.

Comment: The where condition seems unuseful .. remove it ..

Comment: What is the problem with the full table scan? You seem interested in 99,970 rows, so scanning 100,000 is *quite* an efficient way to get them.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE members`.  `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: What percentage of the table is dups?  Is the entire row duplicated?  Or are you only checking a few columns to determine "dup"?  (Both of these questions may lead to different algorithms.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, mi_id, m_id
    FROM members
    ORDER BY mi_id DESC, m_id DESC, id DESC;
```

and have

```
INDEX(mi_id, m_id, id)
```